# Ionic 2: Infinite scrolling not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, infinite-scroll

I am trying to put infinite scrolling onto my app which is pulling data from https://developer.yummly.com/documentation. There is a value of max results which is set to 50 currently. I want it to increase by the same amount each time you get to the scrolling point.

My api call starts here

```
 perpage: number = 50;

 loadCategory(category:any, start:number=0) {
    var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=...&_app_key=...";

    if (categoryCache[category.categoryId]) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(categoryCache[category.categoryId]);
    }

    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
      // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
      var params = "";

      category.apiParams.forEach(paramPair => {
        params += "&" + paramPair.key + '=' + paramPair.value;
      });

      this.http.get(url + params + "&maxResult=" + this.perpage + "&start=" + start)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
          // and save the data for later reference
          console.log(data);
          console.log(this.http.get);
          categoryCache[category.categoryId] = data.matches;
          resolve(categoryCache[category.categoryId]);
        });
    });
 }
```

and then my page .ts file is

```
  public api:  any = [];
  private start:number=50;

  loadRecipes(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.apiAuthentication.loadCategory(this.navParams.data)
      .then(data => {
        this.api = data;
      });
    }) 
  } 


  doInfinite(infiniteScroll:any) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Text goes here
      this.start = 100;
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
```

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `loadRecipies` within `doinfinite()`.
For your pagenation, change `loadRecipies` to:

```
api:any[]=[];//initialize to empty array
loadRecipes(scroll?:any,start?:any){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.apiAuthentication.loadCategory(this.navParams.data,start)
      .then(data => {
        this.api.push(data);
        if(scroll){
          scroll.complete()
        }
      },err=>{
        if(scroll){
          scroll.complete()
        }
      });
    }) 
  }
```

In `doInfinite`,

```
 doInfinite(infiniteScroll:any) {
    this.loadRecipies(infiniteScroll,this.start);
    this.start+=50;
  }
```

Comment: Hi that seems to clear all errors and from putting in a console log it adds in 50 more. But on the front end nothing actually loads in?

Comment: you are creating a new promise in `loadRecipies` any particular reason?

Comment: also you need to push into `this.api` not reset

Comment: This was just the way I learnt to implement this. When pushing data that errors out the whole page

Comment: set the `this.api` to empty array first

Comment: I then get an error of  `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` which is part of the api. If done using the elvis operator I only have 1 empty object loading